# Hide the form when clicked on a particular option of dropdown and show the form when clicked on a particular option of dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I want to show a form when clicked on a particular option of a dropdown and hide the form when clicked on a particular option of a dropdown

This is my html code:

```
<div class="form-group" id="venue-select">
<select class="form-control venue-dropdown" id="" onchange="myFunction()">
<option value="none" id="#hide" ><b>Select Venue Type</b></option>
<option>Theme Restaurant</option>
<option>Blah restaurant</option>
<option>Flana Restaurant</option>
<option>Woops Restaurant</option>
</select>
 </div>
    <div class="row bgcolor show-form" style="display:none;">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <form>
         <div class="form-group">
       <label><strong>Venue Name</strong><sup class = "venue-imp">*</sup></label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Jhanqar Banquet Hall">
</div>
   </form>
   </div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <form>
<div class="form-group">
   <label><strong>Venue Price</strong><sup class = "venue-imp">*</sup></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Jhanqar Banquet Hall">
   </div>
</form>
 </div>
  </div>
```

it's working perfectly when i click on any venue in the dropdown but i want the form to hide when i click on select any venue

this is my javascript code:

```
/*show fom*/
function myFunction() {
    $('.show-form').show();

    //        $('.show-form').hide();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try to this

<select class="form-control venue-dropdown" id="" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
    <option value="Theme Restaurant 1">Theme Restaurant 1</option>
    <option value="Theme Restaurant 2">Theme Restaurant 2</option>
</select>

<script>
 function myFunction(select_value) {
     if(select_value == 'Theme Restaurant 1')
     {
      $('.show-form').show();
     }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: yes it is working but the options will come dynamically how will i be able to give value to them??

Comment: Please put your code here. how to create dynamic option.